# com.mapbox.geojson - is a Point within a Polygon Java

Tags: java, geojson

I am trying to determine whether a com.mapbox.geojson.Point is within a com.mapbox.geojson.Polygon using Java 11. I've looked at other questions surrounding this but can't seem to find an answer. My Polygon contains a list of 5 coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Parts of the Turf Geospacial library has been ported to Java. The method you are looking for is TurfJoins.Inside(), here are the docs: https://docs.mapbox.com/archive/android/java/api/libjava-turf/3.0.1/com/mapbox/turf/TurfJoins.html.